# Use data from ASP.NET web application in VBScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript

What suggestions or methods should I use in trying to get data from an ASP.NET web application using C# such as text from a label control in a VBScript.

I have a button in ASP.net that runs a VBScript like so:

```
OnClientClick="javascript:window.open('file://location/win/drive/folder/folder/script.vbs','_blank')"
```

I have looked at saving the data in a file maybe excel or txt file but when saving to the clients machine it asks them to save it or open it as a download. Preferably I would like no interaction from the user.

Do you have any ideas that could help me?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to run an external VB Script on the client without informing the user?  That seems like bad form.

Comment: No, they know that a script will run as when they click the button which runs the script a pop up appears asking if they want to run it. Thats the only interaction I want from the user.